# Does Pug have access to any server-side functions/variables when rendering a template in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

lets say I'd defined a variable inside my app, and I wanted to use that variable in my Pug template. Is it possible for Pug to access this variable if I don't pass it through in the render statement?

I have a variable whose value will periodically change that should be visible on almost every page of my website. Every page it should be visible from will extend the same template, so if I could somehow access the variable from inside that template I only need to write code in one place. I know that I can include the variable inside the `locals` portion of `res.render('template', { ... })` but this doesn't seem like a practical solution given I could add new routes in future. Does anybody have any idea how I could achieve this in the neatest and most readable way?

Comment: "if I don't pass it through in the render statement?": No.

Comment: @Marc I actually found a solution which doesn't require you pass the variable in the render statement, I've left it as an answer, hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982707/how-to-call-an-external-javascript-function-in-a-pug-file) by tbhaxor, posting in case anybody stumbles onto this in future.

Define your variables/functions inside some `helper.js` file and export them. Then require that file in your `index.js` file e.g. `` const helper = require('./helper.js`); `` so you can now use:

`app.locals.SOME_NAME = helper.someFunctionOrVariable`

Which can be accessed within your template by calling  `- const result = SOME_NAME();`

Hopefully this helps anybody else, all credit to tbhaxor.